# How to create fixed width label for specified width in iOS/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Say I'm creating a calculator and I know I'm going to support a maximum of 20 digits in portrait and 40 digits in landscape.

How do I create or resize a label to display up to my maximum number of digits such that it doesn't keep resizing as we add or remove digits from the result?

Code I've tried so far;

```
let labelFont : UIFont = resultDigitsLabel.font;
let originalString : String = "00000000000000000000";
let nsString : NSString = originalString as NSString;
var labelSize : CGSize = nsString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: labelFont]);
labelSize.height = 0;
let labelRect : CGRect = resultDigitsLabel.frame;
let newFrame :CGRect = CGRect(origin: labelRect.origin, size: labelSize);
resultDigitsLabel.frame = newFrame;

resultDigitsLabel.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
resultDigitsLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

So far no luck, the original frame reset doesn't appear to resize the label and as I add or remove digits the frame (by watching the border) resizes also.

I don't have any size constraints that I see, should I be creating a constraint rather than setting the width by altering the frame?

Any other tips?

Thanks.

Comment: The max width of label can be the width of screen at any point. So add a label and add trailing and leading constraint to the label set the constraint constant as 0. Which will make it cover whole screen width and restrict number of characters to 20 in portrait and 40 in landscape thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint is the best way. Give `Leading` and `Trailing` constraint to your Label and also give `equal width` with the super view.
It will support in both Landscape and Portrait mode.

Comment: Yep, adding constraints did the trick, used to answer and provided code sample in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property to label :- 
resultDigitsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the frame for 20 digits or 40 digits and create the frame for UILabel with that frame.

```
let digits:NSString = "99999999999999999999" as NSString
let idealFrame= digits.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: CGFloat.infinity, height: 30), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:labelFont], context: nil).size
```

Now you can make UILabel this frame.

Comment: Thanks, but this code segment produces the same values as the nsString.size line does in my segment. Problem still is that the on screen label keep resizing as we increase the number of digits in the label.

Answer (score 0):

As per thewarri0r9 above adding constraints did the trick;

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds;
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let constraintMargin = (screenWidth - labelSize.width) / 2;
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: targetDigitsLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: constraintMargin);
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: targetDigitsLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: constraintMargin * -1);
    view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint]);
```